# dropzone.js（ドラッグ＆ドロップでのアップロード）が上手く動作しません。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

以下を参考に実装をしております。
http://plugmin.co/436/

画像をドラッグ＆ドロップしようとしても、
file:///Users/・・・・
となってしまい、ファイルアップロードが上手くできませんでした。

以下のファイルでいうところの
console.log("hoge3")は通っているのですが
console.log("hoge4")は通ってません。

どのようにしたらよいのかわからず、かつ、javascriptのデバッグ方法があまり詳しくないため、詰まっております。

アドバイス頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

ruby 2.2.2
rails 4.0.3

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-dropzone'
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require dropzone
```

$ rake routes

```
  index GET      /index(.:format)     public#index
  root GET      /                    public#index
  upload POST     /upload(.:format)    public#upload
```

ImageUploader自身は他でも使っており、問題なく画像アップロードできております。（ドラッグ＆ドロップではありませんが）

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @chat = Chat.new
  end

  def upload
    chat = Chat.find(params[:id])
    chat.attributes = chat_paramas
    chat.save
  end

  def chat_params
    params.require(:chat).permit(:user_id, :description, :image)
  end

end
```

app/views/public/index.html.erb

```
<div class="uploadArea">
  <%= link_to "", 'javascript:void(0)', class: "uploadZone publish dz-clickable" %>
  <p>
    画像をドラッグ＆ドロップ!
  </p>
</div>
```

以下もapp/views/public/index.html.erb内に記載

```
※scriptの部分はタグ形式にすると、消えてしまったため、以下のように記載します。
script type="text/javascript"

  $(function(){

      // 何かの値をPostしたいなら
      var hogeParam = "hoge";

      // おまじない
      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

      Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
          paramName : "file",         // input fileの名前
          parallelUploads:1,            // 1度に何ファイルずつアップロードするか
          acceptedFiles:'image/*',   // 画像だけアップロードしたい場合
          maxFiles:10,                      // 1度にアップロード出来るファイルの数
          maxFilesize:0.5,                // 1つのファイルの最大サイズ(1=1M)
          dictFileTooBig: "ファイルが大きすぎます。 ({{filesize}}MiB). 最大サイズ: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
          dictInvalidFileType: "画像ファイル以外です。",
          dictMaxFilesExceeded: "一度にアップロード出来るのは10ファイルまでです。",
      };
      // urlは実際に画像をアップロードさせるURLパスを入れる
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".uploadZone.publish",{url: ''});

      console.log("hoge3")
      // 何か値をpostしたい場合
      myDropzone.on("sending", function(file,xhr,formData) {
          console.log("hoge4")
          formData.append("hoge", hogeParam);
      });
  });

/script
```

追記

Satoshi Sachin Ohmoriさんからのご指摘内容をもとに、じっこうしたところ、
インスタンスの生成までは確認できました。

ただ、現状、まだ、ブラウザ上に、画像をドラッグ＆ドロップしても、画像ファイルが読み込まれるだけで、アップロードまではいけませんでした。

エラーログもでず・・・。

```
myDropzone: c
URL: URL()
_callbacks: Object
clickableElements: Array[1]
element: a.uploadZone.publish.dz-clickable
files: Array[0]
hiddenFileInput: input.dz-hidden-input
listeners: Array[2]
options: Object
previewsContainer: a.uploadZone.publish.dz-clickable
version: "4.2.0"
__proto__: c
```

Comment: http://localhost:3000/はエラーが起きず、表示できます。

Answer (score 1):

JavaScriptでのdebug方法について書きます。
JavaScriptでのdebugは`debugger`というメソッドをコードに入れると`debugger`を書いた行で止まってくれるので、そこで今までに定義した変数やメソッドを使うことが出来ます。

サンプルコード:

```
 var foo = "foo";
 debugger # ここでブラウザのJavaScriptの実行が止まるのでfooの変数に出来ます。
```

所謂ブレークポイントという奴です。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。
console.log("hoge3")
の前に、debuggerをいれて、変数などを確認しておりました。

myDropzone: undefined

となっていたのですが、これはつまり、Dropzoneのインスタンスが生成されていないと考えたほうがよろしいでしょうか？どこが原因で動いていないのかがまだ特定できず・・・。

Comment: まずDropzoneの読み込みが上手く言っていないかもしれませんね。
ドラッグアンドドロップしたいページに飛び、ブラウザのソースを読む機能でソースを読み、dropzoneが読み込まれているかを<script src='/path/to/dropzone'>のようになっているか教えて頂けると有難いです。またそれが存在していればコメントして頂けると有難いです。
そこを確認してから対策立てましょう。

Comment: すみません、上にコメントは一旦無視してこっちをやってみてください。 

Gemfileがでうまくrails-assetsが動いてないのではと思いました。
rails-assetsを一旦使わずに書いてみてはいかがでしょうか？
Gemfileの最後の行でもいいので、groupなどに何も入れずに以下を追記してください。

`gem 'rails-assets-dropzone'`

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。https://rails-assets.orgからgemを読み込もうとしていたのをやめて、bundle installし直すと、インスタンスができるところまでは確認できました。ただ、現状、まだ、ブラウザ上に、画像をドラッグ＆ドロップしても、画像ファイルが読み込まれるだけで、アップロードまではいけませんでした。Dropzoneのインスタンスの中身などは質問文の方に追記致しました。

Comment: 画像が読み込まれるというのがよくわからないのですが、どういった状況でしょうか？
例えば、
ドラッグアンドドロップして画像がブラウザ上に表示されているが、dbを見るとデータ的にはアップロードされていない

など。
そこを少し詳しく教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: あと、確認ですが、`var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".uploadZone.publish",{url: ''});`の`{url: ""}部分には実際にはURLを記入しているんですよね。